# Поиск поиск фрагмента изображения на большем изображении или мониторе С++

Tags: python, c++

```
Имеется фрагмент изображения к примеру 30х30 пикселей. Необходимо найти это изображение на большей картинке к примеру скриншоте монитора.
```

В питоне есть простая быстроработающая функция pyautogui.locateOnScreen().
Как реализовать тоже самое на С++.
Если при помощи opencv то какие конкретно функции для этого могут подойти.
Трехдневный поиск не дал каких-либо вразумительных результатов.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Наоборот, это в С++ есть быстроработающая функция cv::matchTemplate, которую использует locateOnScreen. Однако она не простая и не факт, что она нужна в этом случае (так как не приведено определения критерия поиска), а осилить С++ + OpenCV за три дня явно не удастся.

Comment: OpenCV целиком не нужен)).
А matchTemplate норм работает, то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

В OpenCV есть функция [matchTemplate()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)